# Magento 2 custom CLI file thrown error when call function from block?

Tags: magento2, error, cli

What I do wrong in my cli command file?
thrown error when try to clean cache like this "There are no commands defined in the "cache" namespace."

```
class Hicustomer extends Command
    {
     
        protected $myblockobject;
    
        public function __construct(\Vendor\Extension\Block\Mycustomblock $myblockobject)
        {
           $this->myblockobject = $myblockobject;
           parent::__construct();
        }
    
        protected function configure()
        {
            $this->setName('cloudways:hicustomer');
            $this->setDescription('Demo command line');
            parent::configure();
        }
    
        protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
        {
            
           $myblockobject = $this->myblockobject->create()->MyCustomFunction();
    
           
            $output->writeln("Hi Customer");
        }
    }
```

Comment: you need to first confirm : \Vendor\Extension\Block\Mycustombloc this file is available and also this function MyCustomFunction(). Into this one you need to replace your orignal block file path and function name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"There are no commands defined in the "cache" namespace."

This makes me think the issue is above your CLI command.

Make sure magento command are properly installed do `bin/magento list` in the first place and see if the command doesn't fail, if cache:clean is available and if your new command is available too.My guess is that one of these steps will fail.

May be you will be provided more information from `var/log/exception.log` and/or `var/log/system.log`

Comment: Thanks for answer))). I found issue and give answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/348301/100522

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Console;


use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use \Vendor\Module\Helper\Data;

class Hicustomer extends Command
{
   
    
    public function __construct(Data $helper)
    {
            $this->helper = $helper;
            parent::__construct();
    }
    
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('cloudways:hicustomer');
        $this->setDescription('Demo command line');
        parent::configure();
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
       
        $this->helper->checkImage();
      
        $output->writeln("Hi Customer");
    }
}
```

Comment: Change only \Vendor\Module names and try. Works for me)